# Using jQuery autocomplete with AJAX & JSON

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use the jQuery UI autocomplete widget but without success. There is no list of matches presented.

My script is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="./jquery-1.11/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-ui-1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
     $.ajax({
       url: "testAJAX.php",
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {term: request.term},
       success: function(data) {
         response(data);
      }
     });
   } 
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id ="tags" />
</body>
</html>
```

On the server my PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php include "dbConnect.php";
header('Content-type: application/json');

$q=$_POST["term"]; 

$sql="SELECT name, id as value, id FROM sample WHERE id LIKE '".strtoupper($q)."%';";

$result =  mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

$json  = json_encode($rows);
echo $json;
```

I have checked that the AJAX and JSON is working by using the following JQuery script that does output the values from the php.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#path').keyup(function(){
      var t = $('#path').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testAJAX.php",
        data: {term: t},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( data ) {
          $('#tags').html('');
          for (var i in data) {
            $('#tags').append(data[i].value + '<br/>');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="path" />
<div id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I worked it out; I hadn't put the autocomplete in a $(function(){}) block.

So it should be:

```
$(function(){
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "testAJAX.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {term: request.term},
        success: function(data) {
          response(data);
        }
      });
    } 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery Autocomplete** (Get method,Linq,Json) Works 100%

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $("#SearchFirst").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Admin/GetItemList",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {

                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**C#**

```
public ActionResult GetItemList()
{
    var search = Request.Params["term"];

    var itemList = (from items in db.TblItems where items.ItemName.StartsWith(search) select new { label = items.ItemName, value = items.ItemName }).ToList();

    return Json(itemList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```